# Java thread analyzer?

Tags: java, profiler

Is there a Java thread analyzer like the [concurrency analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336027.aspx) in Visual Studio?

Comment: I use YourKit, but you can use VisualVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), nowadays comes as part of the standard Oracle JDK.

Comment: Be sure to download version 1.3.2 and install all the plugins.  It's a significant upgrade

Answer (score 2):

[tda](http://java.net/projects/tda) is a bit crude but it works well and is free. It loads a thread dump and shows threads, locks, deadlocks and multiple threads waiting to acquire a single lock.

Really useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), a fully functional evaluation version is available.

Some screen casts on thread and monitor analysis:

- [Locking graphs in JProfiler](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/11/locking-graphs-in-jprofiler.html)
- [Monitor events versus locking situations](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/01/monitor-events-versus-locking.html)
- [Cumulating and filtering monitor events](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/02/cumulating-and-filtering-monitor-events.html)

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the VS Concurrency Analyzer, but have you tried `jvisualvm`, which is bundled with the Java SDK?

Documentation is [here](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used Eclipse TPTP to debug some threading and profiling issues in the past. It is nice, free, and is integrated well into Eclipse:

Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform
http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/